# How does forward-list work for "<>" in c++-mode?

Tags: balanced-parentheses, cc-mode, syntax-table

I am trying to understand how `forward-list` matches template delimiters `<>` in `c++-mode`.

`forward-list` in `lisp.el` calls `scan-lists` with the appropriate arguments. The documentation for `scan-lists` says

> `(scan-lists FROM COUNT DEPTH)`
>
> Scan from character number `FROM` by `COUNT` lists. Scan forward if `COUNT`
>   is positive, backward if `COUNT` is negative. Return the character
>   number of the position thus found.
>
> A "list", in this context, refers to a balanced parenthetical
>   grouping, as determined by the syntax table.

Looking at the syntax table in a `c++-mode` buffer, I don't find an entry of which indicates that `<` and `>` match each other. Is my reading of the syntax table incorrect? I am assuming that matching entries look like this:

```
(       ()  which means: open, matches )
)       )(  which means: close, matches (
```

To summarize, how does `forward-list` match the template delimiters `<` and `>` in `c++-mode`?

Comment: It looks like some magic from `scan_lists` in syntax.c. For instance, delimiters in `#include <vector>` aren't matched, while in `vector<int>` they are.

Comment: C++ is horribly hard to parse. Simply matching `<` to `>` wouldn't work because you have both binary comparisons, and bitshift operators. Any C++ mode will need to determine whether any given chevron "belongs" to another or stands on its own.